# Three.js: poor performance in Chrome for Windows

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have what I thought was a fairly simple effect running in Three.js with react-three-fiber. The demo was a reflective model that "looks" at the user's cursor. It runs splendidly in Chrome and Safari for Mac, but the performance on Chrome for Windows falls off the cliff (even on a system with a fancy GPU).

Things I’ve tried…

- removed the mouse tracking outside of React (prevents React from unnecessarily rendering component at 64fps, but no visible performance improvement)
- replaced `mesh.rotation = newRotation` with `mesh.quaternion.slerp()`
- using `<AdaptiveDpr pixelated />` to reduce resolution from "retina grade" to chunky style (helps a *little*)
- turning off anti-aliasing (doesn't help)
- replacing mouse tracking with a simple rotation (doesn't help!)

I’m at my wits end with this… there's a repo at https://github.com/EricWVGG/three-cube-demo, and you can see a demo at https://calicoc.at

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your demo link does not work

Comment: Apologies, fixed

Comment: performs ok on my windows 10 chrome 94.0.4606.61